# url with `\urlstyle(same)` seems to force `lowtilde`

Tags: ieeetran, urls, tilde

When using `\urlstyle{same}`, the `url` package will substitute a low 'faked' tilde, even if the `lowtilde` option is not specified:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

Tilde: \textasciitilde

Not a tilde: \url{~}

\end{document}
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way to overrule this?

I am using the `IEEEtran` class, which forces the `\urlstyle{same}` option, and I am submitting to a journal, so I'd rather not load the `hyperref` package (which is suggested as a workaround elsewhere on this site) because that may not be allowed / be silently removed in editing.

Comment: Use `\def\UrlTildeSpecial{\do\~{\hbox{\textasciitilde}}}` but see Mico's answer also.

Comment: simply `\def\UrlTildeSpecial{}` should be enough. But better is not to use OT1 encoding. As you mention copy&paste in a comment below: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` resolves this and other copy&paste problems.

Comment: @yannisl Thanks! That works, but I just realised that there is a secondary issue, namely that with the default font, `\textasciitilde` produces a combining tilde rather than the ascii tilde.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, ~ indeed copies correctly, even the lowered version. I still believe the url package is not behaving according to its own specifications, but my underlying problem is solved. What I don't understand is why with T1 encoding, the high and the lowered tilde suddenly copy as the same character (the ascii tilde), while with OT1 encoding they copy as two different (non-ascii!) characters. That runs entirely counter to the idea that OT1 has the smaller character set and is restricted to ascii.

Comment: ot1 has only place for 128 characters but it has to provide text symbols which are not in ascii (like accents) and that can be quite challenging and leads to various problems (not only in copy&paste), e.g. it fakes the tilde with the tilde accent. Simply avoid the encoding. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675103/2388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is in the definition of `\Url@OTnonTT`, where `\UrlTildeSpecial` is used instead of `\Url@force@Tilde`.

The last command is `\relax`, unless `lowtilde` has been specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\def\Url@OTnonTT{\do\<{\langle}\do\>{\mathbin{\rangle}}\do
  \_{\_\penalty\@m}\do\|{\mid}\do\{{\lbrace}\do\}{\mathbin{\rbrace}}\do
  \\{\mathbin{\backslash}}\Url@force@Tilde}% <--- it had \UrlTildeSpecial
\makeatother

\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

Tilde: \textasciitilde

Not a tilde: \url{~}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from p. 382 of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) [emphasis added]:

> Note that `\textasciitilde` and `\~{}` produce raised, diacritic tildes. “Text” (i.e., vertically centered) tildes can be generated with either the math-mode `\sim` command ..., which produces a somewhat wide “∼”, or the `textcomp` package's `\texttildelow`, which produces a vertically centered “~” in most fonts but a baseline-oriented “~” in Computer Modern, txfonts, pxfonts, and various other fonts originating from the TEX world. *If your goal is to typeset tildes in URLs or Unix filenames, your best bet is to use the `url` package* ...

In short, what you call a "faked tilde" is, in fact, a vertically centered symbol which should be perfectly acceptable when it's used in text-mode settings, and especially when it's used in URL strings.

Comment: Mico the OPs issue is with the `url` package that needs an update! I just went over it quickly handles different encodings but not TU. So the package is forcing the math-mode. See my comment at the question.

Comment: @yannisl - I’m not sure I follow you. At present, I can’t see a good reason for preferring the diacritic-level symbol produced by `\textasciitilde` over a slightly lower-placed version of the same glyph if the symbol clearly is not intended to function as a diacritic mark.

Comment: The reason why this is not acceptable in my situation, is because when you go and copy the resulting url into an address bar, as one of my reviewers did, you don't get the correct address, and it's not at all obvious why. That's why I call it a 'faked' tilde, because it's not the same character.

Comment: You haven't explained why this happens or what to do about it. The `url` documentation claims that "Normal treatment of the ~ character is to use the font’s `\textasciitilde`
character", unless one specifies the `lowtilde` option, which I haven't.

Comment: @oulenz - Please give an example of a real-world URL that contains a tilde. That would help me investigate further.

Comment: @Mico It's quite common in personal academic websites, e.g. `https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~charles/statlog/index.html`. But as suggested by UlrikeFischer in the comment thread to my question, the copying/pasting is solved with T1 encoding. I do think it's still an issue that the `url` package lowers the tilde even though the `lowtilde` option is not called, since it's inconsistent and goes against the package documentation. And if we want lowered tildes to be the default and high tildes the exception, then that should be properly implemented and documented in the `url` package.